# Is $x^\pi$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For real-valued functions such as $x^2$ or $x^\sqrt{2}$ we can show that they are continuous using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, because the exponent is an algebraic number.

But what if say $f(x):=x^\pi$, or $f(x):=x^e$ ? how can we rigorously prove that they are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How do you define $(-2)^\pi?$

Comment: When $x>0$, $x^{\pi} = e^{\pi\ln(x)}$ a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: it's equal to -8.82497782708... according to google calculator. But I think it uses the rounded up value of $\pi$, which is of course algebraic.

Comment: I guess you typed $-2^{\pi}!$ For $(-2)^{\pi}$ Google returns
$-7.9661783 - 3.7973987 i$

Comment: How do you (rigorously) prove the continuity of $x^\sqrt{2}$ on $\Bbb R$? How do you define it for negative x?

Comment: For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x)=x^a$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{\color{red}{+}}$ by its very definition, $\exp\left(a\log x\right).$

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$, If we take $f(x)=e^{\pi\log(x)}$ and plug it into the MacLaurin Series for the exponential function, we see that it is [uniformally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Exponential_function), which implies continuity. Same argument can be applied to $x^e$.

EDIT: This might help too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

$f(x) =π\log(x)$ is continuous for $x>0.$

$g(y) = \exp(y)$ is continuous for $y \in \mathbb{R}.$

The composition $g(f(x)) $ continuous for $x >0.$

$g(f(x)) = = \exp(π\log x) = x^π$.

Note: $π, e$ are real numbers.